# Is it possible to build functions within a function in C?

Tags: c, functional-programming

For a class assignment we are writing a program which takes in input, and sorts each line of input with qsort with strcmp as its comparator function. Because the type of strcmp is not the same as required by qsort, a wrapper function needs to be built to satisfy qsort.

I wasn't satisfied with this, and wanted to write a function which takes in a function of type:

```
int (*cmp)(const char *, const char *)
```

and returns a function of type:

```
int (*qsortcmp)(const void *, const void *)
```

Is this possible? Have I been writing too much haskell? I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not support lambda functions.  Your only choice is to create a function of the type expected by `qsort` and call `strcmp` from inside of that function.

For example:

```
int qsort_cmp_str(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *s1 = a;
    const char *s2 = b;
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
```

Comment: Figured my brain was too deep into functional programming. Thank you for you answer!

Comment: @Sam Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible only with a global variable that holds the real function to call.  (Yes, that’s horrible.)

There is a reason: a function pointer with only the obvious parameters cannot represent a *closure*.  Had `qsort` accepted a pointer of type

```
int (*)(void *closure, const void*, const void*)
```

and a `void*` to pass it for each comparison, it would be possible to write a converter:

```
struct char_qsorter {
  int (*function)(void*, const char*, const char*);
  void *param;
};
struct qsorter {
  int (*function)(void*, const void*, const void*);
  void *param;
};

int char_qsort_wrapper(void *closure, const void *a, const void *b) {
  const char_qsorter *const cq=closure;
  return cq->function(cq->param, a, b);
}
qsorter convert(const char_qsorter *cq) {
  const qsorter ret={char_qsort_wrapper, cq};
  return ret;
}

/* Convert a plain function pointer: */
int trivial_wrapper(void *closure, const char *a, const char *b) {
  return (*(int (*const *)(const char*, const char*))closure)(a, b);
}
char_qsorter trivial_closure(int (*const *f)(const char*, const char*)) {
  const char_qsorter ret={trivial_wrapper, f};
  return ret;
}

void sort_strings(const char *const *ss, size_t n) {
  int (*const f0)(const char*, const char*)=strcmp;
  const char_qsorter cq=trivial_closure(&f0);
  const qsorter q=convert(&cq);
  qsort_closure(ss, n, sizeof(*ss), q.function, q.param);
  /* or just pass q if the library used the struct */
}
```

I think it’s obvious why in practice people prefer the hardcoded solution where it’s sufficient.  (Really, lazy programmers just pass `strcmp` directly, which works on most implementations.)

C11 does support this with [`qsort_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), but it’s a special optional function with weird runtime error checking added on.

Comment: Than you! It seems I've been spoiled by function currying.

Comment: @Sam: I would say it’s capture, not currying, that you’re missing, but yes, Haskell spoils us.